# How to declare list of int table in c#?

Tags: c#, list, declaration

I have declaration as follow:

```
IList<int[]> populacja = new List<int[]>();
```

but I want to declare also a constant size of int table. So I want something like this

```
IList<int[2]> populacja = new List<int[2]>();
```

How to do that? What is a good solution for making list of int table ?

Comment: just do int[] populacja = new int[2];

Comment: You could also make it an `IList<Tuple<int, int>>` depending on your needs

Comment: @elgonzo But it limits first list to two elements. I want to make dynamic list with constant length table.

Comment: Did he mean int[][2]?

Comment: Yeah, i guess @moarboilerplate understood the question correctly... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's important for you to ensure that `populacja` is always int[2], you can wrap it in a class, then make a list of that class.  Built in options include [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx), for example:

```
IList<Tuple<int,int>> populacja = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();
```

Comment: populacja always have elements of type int[2] but it's limit to the capabilities of tuple. How can I do that when I want to make int[1243]?

Comment: You're saying you may want instead of an int[2] and int[1243]?  I would suggest at that point that you create a class that is a wrapper to an int[1243] and use that instead of Tuple.

Comment: If you're finding yourself requiring lots of these things of different sizes, then I'd suggest that you don't really want a List<int[]>, but rather a good old-fashioned int[][].  List<x> implies that x is a first-class object of some sort, which usually maps to some entity.  Lots of arrays of arbitrary lengths kinda feels like it's working against OOP principles, though I can't be certain as it's not my problem domain.

Comment: Ok, thanks, thats the solution for me but it is not look efficiently.

Comment: For what it's worth, I haven't used a 2-dimensional array or anything to hold ints like that in C# since .NET Framework 1.1...as GWLlosa mentioned you may need to solve the problem in a different, object-oriented fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI.

The reason you cant declare int[2] in IList is because it is expecting a type. In this case, the type is an array of int (int[]). The T doesn't care about the length or anything like that. If you did want to use int[] you will need to do something like this --

```
        IList<int[]> populacja = new List<int[]>();
        populacja.Add(new int[2]); // empty int array of size 2
        populacja.Add(new [] { 3211,3212 }); // non-empty int array of size 2
```

Every time you add a new array of int, you will need to explicitly instantiate it with a size of 2 since there is no constraint.

Comment: But in your solution I can add to populacja new int[4]. Am I right? I want to make size constant.

Comment: Correct, you need to create the constraint yourself. populacja is a list of arrays, the list doesn't know what size each array is. It is your responsibility to put a constraint in place. The best way is to wrap populacja in its own class and create an Add method that enforces the int[2] constraint.

Comment: The solution of GWLlosa is good but I wonder if there is better way in case of efficiently.

Comment: It depends how you are using populacja. There are many ways to improve performance but its not possible for me to give you any advice without known how you use it. For example, if you are always iterating over the list then there is not much you can do as it will always be o(n). But, if you are doing look-ups, then maybe you can utilize a dictionary/hashmap of some sort.